# Cannot shutdown (CLI/GUI)

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I have problem with shutting down my laptop (Asus UX42VD) on Ubuntu 12.04.
And I have no idea what could cause this problem.

Now after clicking on buttons **Restart** or **Shut down**, it just logs me off.

I was used not to shut down computer via terminal, because that doesn't work either ever since. It just gets stuck in CLI showing this on screen without ability to write any commands there:

```
* Error: Could not create log file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                              [fail]
* jetty is not installed
                        Starting memcached: memcached.                                   [OK]
* Starting message broker rabbit-server
Broadcast message from chyno@chyno
     (/dev/pts/3) at 8:56 ...

The system is going down for maintenance NOW!
Skip stopping firewall: ufw (not enabled)
                                         * Stopping web server apache2
*
  * Stopping ElasticSearch Server                                                        [OK]
* Disabling power management...                                                          [OK]
  * jetty is not installed
Stopping memcached: memcached.
* Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
* message broker already stopped                                                         [OK]
```

Any thoughts appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: does it behave the same way if you try commands like **sudo poweroff** or **sudo shutdown now** ?

Comment: Open up the terminal, type `sudo halt` and try seeing if you get any error messages. If so edit your question and include them here.

Comment: @OluDoug poweroff command actually powers off computer. Didn't know this command. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Parto No, it stucks on ubuntu loading screen.

Comment: I've also posted possibly related question to this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525805/cli-no-ability-to-interact